# Migrating from an IMAP email to Google Workspace email - no password asked?

Tags: email, imap, migration, google-workspace

I am migrating from an IMAP email to Google Workspace email. There is a migration tool available which asks only for "source email" and target "Google Workspace email" - it does not ask for email account password. And it works OK, all emails have been transfered from this old IMAP server to new Google Workspace emails:

`me@mydomain.com (IMAP) -> me@mydomain.com (Google Workspace email)`

`user1@mydomain.com (IMAP) -> user1@mydomain.com (Google Workspace email)`
etc.

How come it works OK, and it did not ask me for a password, only "source email" address? How did it unlock the `user1@mydomain.com` mailbox without a password? The tool did not ask anything about my IMAP server other than the address, which is `imap.mycompany.com`.

Answer (score 0):

If the tool was installed in the same server or network where the IMAP server is located, then probably it has access to the mailboxes without a need of a password. What type of authentication did you use to access the tool?  There are some migration tools using OAuth2 and service accounts so then password is not required even if they use IMAP protocol to migrate. I'd recommend reading the migration tool docs to understand how it connects to the servers.

Comment: I don't know which tool Google uses underneath. I am just using the Migration option within the Google Workspace web user interface.

Comment: The Google Admin console Data Migration service always asks for the IMAP source password. This is explained at https://support.google.com/a/answer/9476255?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-migrate-email-from-imap-based-webmail-providers so maybe you did input your password in the configuration steps for the "Role account". You can double check by ending and restarting the migration.